# Add uipickerview stored in object to viewcontroller's view

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Many people on SO suggest using a uipickerview and a uitextfield to make a dropdown-like interface. I having a pickerview stored in an object. How can I then add this to a viewcontroller's view when the textfield is tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the pickerview, store only the datasource in the dropdown class. Make the ViewController the delegate of the dropdown class. When the textfield begins editing, call a delegate method to set the datasource of the pickerview the the viewcontroller to the dropdown

Dropdown Delegate protocol:

```
protocol DropdownDelegate : class {
    func activateDropdown(dropdown: Dropdown)
}
```

Dropdown class:

```
class Dropdown: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var dataSouce : String = []

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self {
            if(dropdownDelegate != nil) {
                dropdownDelegate?.activateDropdown(dropdown: self)
                textField.endEditing(true)
            }
        }
    }
    //rest of delegate methods
 }
```

ViewController class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, DropdownDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    func activateDropdown(dropdown: Dropdown) {
        self.pickerView.delegate = dropdown
        self.pickerView.dataSource = dropdown
    }

    func deactivateDropdown() {
        changeDropdownStatus(status: true)
        self.pickerView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```